# Anylogic Z-score table

Tags: anylogic, cumulative-sum

Is there any way to import and use the Z-score table (Standard normal distribution) in Anylogic for calculating the Cumulative Distribution Function?

For example, assume we have F(Z)=A, in which F(z) is the cumulative distribution function for Standard normal distribution. The note is that we need to import the Z-score table and the way for searching the value in this table and then give us the output.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what does the table look like? Why not simply import into the AnyLogic dbase and query it there?